# Laravel doesn't work properly - Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to install laravel on my new laptop. Whenever I try to create new laravel project i get this message:

Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./test"
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6)
Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php-8.2.11\php.ini
Now trying to download from source

- Syncing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6) into cache

  - Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.6): Cloning 36047268f1 from cache
    Created project in C:\Users\jedro\Desktop\Programy\PHP/test
    @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.25.2] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.16.0].
- league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.13.0].
- league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.16.0] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, 3.16.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.13.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.16.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.25.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\php-8.2.11\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

The project is created but I'm not sure if it works properly. How do I fix it? I tried reinstalling PHP and Composer but it didn't fix it.
When I try php --ini I get this message:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php-8.2.11\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: "_require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension_" ... "_To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - C:\php-8.2.11\php.ini_"

Comment: uncomment this line in your php.ini => `;extension=zip` to `extension=zip`, I suggest to use some windows servers WAMP, XAMP, Laragon, they setup the the neccessary things for your PHP projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Psylogic suggested just uncomment `;extension=zip` line in your php.ini file. and also `;extension=fileinfo`.

Just like

```
 extension=zip
 extension=fileinfo
```

Even after this if you get error for another extension then do the same with that also if it present in your php.ini file.